# image uploading error

Tags: php, mysql

I want to upload image on mysql database by php. I use it before without any trouble but now i can't. Here is my code ::

image.php

```
 <form action='image2.php' method='POST' entype='multipart/form-data'>
    <b> Code :: </b> <input type='text' name='randomValue'>  <br />
      <b> Upload your image :: </b> <input type='file' name='image'> <br />
     <input type='submit' name='submitX' value='Complete Registration'>
 </form>
```

image2.php

```
 if(  isset($_POST['submitX'] ) )   {
     include('DB.php');

     $test = trim( addslashes( $_POST['randomValue'] ) );

     $image = addslashes( file_get_contents( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] ) );
     $size =  getimagesize( $_FILES['image']['tmp_name'] );

     if( $size > 0  ) {
        mysql_query(" INSERT INTO test VALUES ('' , '$test', '$image') ") or die(mysql_error());
     }

     }

     ?>
```

And the error is ::

```
 Warning: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: Filename cannot be empty in  E:\xampp\htdocs\MyWork\test\image2.php on line 8

  Warning: getimagesize() [function.getimagesize]: Filename cannot be empty in E:\xampp\htdocs\MyWork\test\image2.php on line 9
```

Answer (score 0):

You have no element on form with name `img_name` please change it to `image_name` in form

```
  <b> Upload your image :: </b> <input type='file' name='image_name'> <br />
```

OR

`$_POST['image']` in code where getting data from post.

```
   $test = trim( addslashes( $_POST['img_name'] ) );
```

should be

```
   $test = trim( addslashes( $_POST['name'] ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

Buddy, I think the query was correct.

Simple mistake u made

```
<form action='image2.php' method='POST' entype='multipart/form-data'>
```

in above u miss "**c**" in enctype

```
<form enctype='multipart/form-data'>
```

otherwise no problem it's working